# Place author name between title and affiliation

Tags: titles, titling

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{
    {Some fancy title for a fancy paper}\\
    {\author{Author 1 \and Author 2}}
    {\large{University of \LaTeX}}
    {\date{April 2018}}
}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: titlepage]

I would like to have the university name appear between the authors and the date, not between the title and the authors.

I have tried to defined the university name after the authors name, but with no luck. I have also tried a couple of different approaches, but I can't seem to get them to work with the \author command. Am I missing something?

Note that both authors are from the same university, hence why I want to list the university name only once in the title.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** making the following adjustment seems to work as intended:

```
\title{
    {Some fancy title for a fancy paper}\\
    {\author{Author 1 \and Author 2}}
    {\date{University of \LaTeX \\[2ex] April 2018}}
}
```

But wouldn't it be considered bad practice to include the affiliation in the \date command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` typesets your title according to some values stored by means of macros such as `\title`, `\author`, `\date` (those are the basic ones, depending on your documentclass, you may have a larger set).

So, you should not put all of these things "inside title" for `\maketitle` to work. Normally, you'd go with something like:

```
\title{The Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{April 2018}
\maketitle
```

Now, since you want to have the institution alongside, you can use the `date` field:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Some fancy title for a fancy paper}
\author{Author 1 \and Author 2}
\date{{\large University of \LaTeX} \\
  April 2018}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]