# Include fields in the title of a document

Tags: titles, article

I am trying to make a problem set in maths to hand it out to students. In the title there is the `\title`,`\author` and `\date` of the document, however

1. I would like to include two more fields: the name of the **institution** I am working for and the name of the **course**
2. The name of the author is not that important, so I would like it to appear smaller.

Below I am leaving a MWE of what I have, any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\usepackage{amssymb,
            amsmath,
            lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol} % to insert columns
    \setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=cyan,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=blue,
        }
\usepackage{parskip} % For no indentation and a bit of space in paragraphs

% to format enumerate to letters
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} % <-- note the option 'inline'

\begin{document}

\title{Problem Set 2}
\author{Ruben Perez Sanz}
\date{7 September, 2020}
\maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: please have a look if the answer meets the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no placement has been given for the University and Course I have used my own from __ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429148/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]} 
 {\end{trivlist}}

\usepackage{amssymb,
            amsmath,
            lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol} % to insert columns
    \setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=cyan,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=blue,
        }
\usepackage{parskip} % For no indentation and a bit of space in paragraphs

% to format enumerate to letters
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} % <-- note the option 'inline'

\begin{document}

\title{Problem Set 2}
\author{Ruben Perez Sanz}
\date{{\large University of \LaTeX} \\[2em]
    \large Course on Fitment of Title\\[2em]
    April 2018}
\maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```